# Error "Only valid bearer authentication supported" when requesting access token from Spotify

Tags: node.js, spotify

I'm trying to get an oAuth access token from Spotify (Step 4 in their [Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)).

I believe, I send all required parameters as described in their docs, but Spotify responds with:

```
"error": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Only valid bearer authentication supported"
}
```

This is my request in node.js:

```
function getToken(code){
    var idAndSecret = config.clientId+':'+config.clientSecret;
    var authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(idAndSecret).toString('base64');
    var data = querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
    });
    var tokenReq = https.request({
        hostname: 'api.spotify.com',
        path: '/api/token?'+data,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authString
        }
    }, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            console.log(new Buffer(chunk).toString());
        });
        console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    });

    tokenReq.end();
}
```

I already checked my clientId, clientSecret, auth-code and redirectUri.

This is the Response Header:

```
{
    "server":"nginx",
    "date":"Sat, 02 Jan 2016 23:58:58 GMT",
    "content-type":"application/json",
    "content-length":"99",
    "connection":"close",
    "www-authenticate":"Bearer realm=\\"spotify\\",
    error=\\"invalid_request\\", 
    error_description=\\"Only valid bearer authentication supported\\"",
    "access-control-allow-origin":"*",
    "access-control-allow-methods":"GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
    "access-control-allow-credentials":"true",
    "access-control-max-age":"604800",
    "access-control-allow-headers":"Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was the wrong endpoint: it should be accounts.spotify.com not api.spotify.com

Then I got a status 500 & I also fixed this:

```
function getToken(code){
    var idAndSecret = config.clientId+':'+config.clientSecret;
    var authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(idAndSecret).toString('base64');
    var data = querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
    });
    var tokenReq = https.request({
        hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',
        path: '/api/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authString,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    }, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            console.log(new Buffer(chunk).toString());
        });
        console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    });

    tokenReq.end(data);
}
```

Comment: you save me from continuing wasting my time. I was using the wrong hostname and breaking my head why Postman worked and not my app. Thanks!!